# Counting number of event occurrences within time period of another event

Tags: r, conditional-statements, countif

I am having trouble figuring out the best way to count the number of events that happen 10s before and after another event.

I have multiple subjects undergoing multiple experimental sessions. In my dataframe, I have:

- Subject
- Session
- Event1 count
- Event1 timestamp (a row for each occurence)
- Event2 label (4 different types of event type)
- Event2 timestamp

For example:

| Subject | Session | Event1Count | Event1Timestamp | Event2Label | Event2Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| K1 | 01 | 1 | 476 | NA | NA |
| K1 | 01 | 2 | 2444 | NA | NA |
| K1 | 01 | 3 | 4922 | NA | NA |
| K1 | 01 | NA | NA | Type1 | 483 |
| K1 | 01 | NA | NA | Type1 | 2448 |
| K1 | 01 | NA | NA | Type2 | 2452 |
| K1 | 01 | NA | NA | Type2 | 4920 |
| L2 | 01 | 1 | 35 | NA | NA |
| L2 | 01 | 2 | 310 | NA | NA |
| L2 | 01 | 3 | 1933 | NA | NA |
| L2 | 02 | NA | NA | Type 2 | 30 |
| L2 | 02 | NA | NA | Type 2 | 32 |
| L2 | 02 | NA | NA | Type 2 | 305 |
| L2 | 02 | NA | NA | Type 1 | 1941 |
| K1 | 02 | 1 | 131 | NA | NA |
| K1 | 02 | 2 | 659 | NA | NA |
| K1 | 02 | 3 | 3802 | NA | NA |
| K1 | 02 | NA | NA | Type1 | 137 |
| K1 | 02 | NA | NA | Type1 | 657 |
| K1 | 02 | NA | NA | Type1 | 665 |

I wish to count the number of each Event2 type occurring 10 seconds before and after each Event1 occurrence. From the example above, I wish to receive:

| Subject | Session | Event1Count | Pre-Event1 Type1 | Post-Event1 Type1 | Pre-Event1 Type2 | Post-Event1 Type2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| K1 | 01 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| K1 | 01 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| K1 | 01 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| L2 | 01 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| L2 | 01 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| L2 | 01 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| K1 | 02 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| K1 | 02 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| K1 | 02 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

This information can be in a new dataframe or added to the same one, it does not matter. It is the conditional counting that I am having difficulty with.

I hope this explanation makes sense. I could probably have made the example clearer.

I have tried various methods suggested for other questions posted on this forum, but have had no success as many of the other questions have set time windows and are looking at only 1 column of data, whereas I am trying to count the rows in 1 column based on the time before and after a time in each row for a different column.

It may be that I have organised my data inefficiently and it would be easier to use separate dataframes for Event1 and Event2 data.

Comment: your desired output seems not valid considering your sample data provided. For eaaxmple: L2 - session 01 has no Type2 eventes, these only occur in L2 - session 02... typo?

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing is by using the `dput` function on the data or a subset of the data you are using, then pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: Yep, you guys are correct, my bad. It was meant to be all Session 01.  Thanks for the Youtube link, it was very useful and I'll make sure to use this method in future questions!

Answer (score 0):

your desired output seems not to match your criteria/sample data.. but I believe you are looking for something like this?

```
library(data.table)
#if not a data.table format already, make it so
setDT(DT)

# first, split into two parts
DT1 <- DT[!is.na(Event1Count), ]
DT2 <- DT[is.na(Event1Count), ]

# create unique item for each row, to iterate over later (using .EACHI)
DT1[, id := .I]
# set the data.table key
setkey(DT1, id)
# perform a self join, using each row to filter DT2 and pass results
DT1[DT1, c("PreEvent1Type1", "PostEvent1Type1", "PreEvent1Type2",   "PostEvent1Type2") := {
  temp <- DT2[Subject == i.Subject & 
                Session == i.Session & 
                Event2Timestamp >= (i.Event1Timestamp - 10) & 
                Event2Timestamp <= (i.Event1Timestamp + 10), ]
  list(nrow(temp[Event2Label == "Type1" & Event2Timestamp < i.Event1Timestamp, ]),
       nrow(temp[Event2Label == "Type1" & Event2Timestamp >= i.Event1Timestamp, ]),
       nrow(temp[Event2Label == "Type2" & Event2Timestamp < i.Event1Timestamp, ]),
       nrow(temp[Event2Label == "Type2" & Event2Timestamp >= i.Event1Timestamp, ]))
}, by = .EACHI][, c(1:3,8:11)] # <-- this last vector is to select desired columns

#    Subject Session Event1Count PreEvent1Type1 PostEvent1Type1 PreEvent1Type2 PostEvent1Type2
# 1:      K1       1           1              0               1              0               0
# 2:      K1       1           2              0               1              0               1
# 3:      K1       1           3              0               0              1               0
# 4:      L2       1           1              0               0              0               0
# 5:      L2       1           2              0               0              0               0
# 6:      L2       1           3              0               0              0               0
# 7:      K1       2           1              0               1              0               0
# 8:      K1       2           2              1               1              0               0
# 9:      K1       2           3              0               0              0               0
```

**sample data used**

```
DT <- fread("Subject    Session     Event1Count     Event1Timestamp     Event2Label     Event2Timestamp
K1  01  1   476     NA  NA
K1  01  2   2444    NA  NA
K1  01  3   4922    NA  NA
K1  01  NA  NA  Type1   483
K1  01  NA  NA  Type1   2448
K1  01  NA  NA  Type2   2452
K1  01  NA  NA  Type2   4920
L2  01  1   35  NA  NA
L2  01  2   310     NA  NA
L2  01  3   1933    NA  NA
L2  02  NA  NA  Type2   30
L2  02  NA  NA  Type2   32
L2  02  NA  NA  Type2   305
L2  02  NA  NA  Type1   1941
K1  02  1   131     NA  NA
K1  02  2   659     NA  NA
K1  02  3   3802    NA  NA
K1  02  NA  NA  Type1   137
K1  02  NA  NA  Type1   657
K1  02  NA  NA  Type1   665")
```